# Combine the numbers in the brackets adjacently

Tags: python, string

I want to write a function to combine the numbers in the brackets adjacently.
For example, this string as the input

```
(4)2(2)(2)(2)2(2)
```

I want the output is

```
(4)2(6)2(2)
```

And for example, this string as the input

```
(2)(2)2(2)(2)(2)24
```

I want the output is

```
(4)2(6)24
```

Currently I wrote a function as follows:

```
def Combine(i,accumulate,s):
    if s[i] == '(':
        accumulate += int(s[i+1])
        for i in range(i+3,len(s),3):
            if s[i] == '(':
                accumulate += int(s[i+1])
            else:
                print s[i-3] + s[i-2] + s[i-1]
                i += 3
                break
    else:
        print s[i]
        i += 1


Combine(0,0,'(4)2(2)(2)(2)2(2)')
```

And the output is only:

```
(4)
```

I know maybe I need recursive method, but I don't know how to use it correctly.
Can anyone help me?

And I treat it as one-digit problem, and after the sum, I need to convert the number which is more than nine to a corresponding alphabet.

Following is the function:

```
def toStr(n,base):
convertString = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
if n < base:
  return convertString[n]
else:
  return toStr(n//base,base) + convertString[n%base]
```

So for example, the input(the base is 17):

> (16)

The output needs to be:

> (G)

Because I don't know how to modify the function

```
re.sub(r'((\(\d\))+)', f, '(2)(2)(2)(2)(2)(2)(2)(2)')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use regex for that:

```
import re

def f(m):
    return '({0})'.format(sum(int(x) for x in m.group(1)[1::3]))

re.sub(r'((\(\d\))+)', f, '(4)2(2)(2)(2)2(2)') # (4)2(6)2(2)
```

The second argument of [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can be a function, which you can use to compute the sum:

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence
>   of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and
>   returns the replacement string.

`m.group(1)` is the matched string, `m.group(1)[1::3]` is the matched string without parentheses.

`sum(int(x) for x in m.group(1)[1::3])` gets us the sum of all digits in the string.

`'({0})'.format(sum(int(x) for x in m.group(1)[1::3]))` wraps the sum with parentheses (this is the replacement string).

---

Please note that the code above only works for one-digit numbers. If this is a problem, you'd use

```
import re

def f(m):
    matched = m.group(1).strip('()').split(')(')
    return '({0})'.format(sum(int(x) for x in matched))

re.sub(r'((\(\d+\))+)', f, '(42)(2)2') # (44)2
```